# Function for cosine transformation around $\pi/2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given the cosine of an angle $x$ relatively close to $\pi/2$, is there a function $f$ such as: $f(cos(x))=cos((x+\pi/2)/2)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just want a function $f$ so that $f(\cos(x))=\cos((x+\pi/2)/2)$ for $x$ close to $\pi/2$. First do the following using trigonometric identities:
$$
f(\cos(x)) = \cos\left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
f(\cos(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)
$$
So if we can write $\cos(x/2)$ and $\sin(x/2)$ in terms of $\cos(x)$, then we can write $f$ explicitly. But this is simple remembering the half angle formula (or we can just derive it using the cosine double angle formula since I don't remember the half angle one hehe) For $\cos$, we have
$$
\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1 \implies \cos(x) = 2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) - 1 \implies \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos(x)}{2}}
$$ taking the positive root since $\cos(x/2)$ is positive assuming $x$ is close to $\pi/2$. For $\sin$, we have
$$
\cos(2x) = 1- 2\sin^2(x) \implies \cos(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \implies \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 -\cos(x)}{2}}
$$ since $\sin(x/2)$ is positive for $x$ near $\pi/2$. So, going back to the actual function, we have
$$
f(\cos(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos(x)}{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1 -\cos(x)}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1 + \cos(x)} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1 - \cos(x)}
$$
So now we can just replace $\cos(x)$ with $u$ to get
$$
f(u) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1 + u} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1 - u}
$$

Comment: That's right, thank you. Just for mere curiosity, what would have happened if we generalize the mean function in order to have an arbitrary convergence to $0$ like $f(cos(x))=cos\left(\frac{x+a\frac{\pi}{2}}{a+1}\right)$ with $a>100$ for example? A lot of weird stuff happens if I do the calcs by hand.

Comment: @user2464424 So $a$ is some odd integer greater than $100$ right (since you want convergence to $0$ and $\cos$ is $0$ on odd multiples of $\pi/2$)? And I am assuming you still want $x$ to be close to $a\pi/2$. In that case the denominator inside $\cos$ should still be $2$ because you are still taking the arithmetic mean. Most of the steps in my answer will still stay the same but when using the half angle formula, you have to take the right sign in from of the square root and so you have to introduce some formulas in terms of $\cos(x)$ for the sign (which may get a bit messy).